# I made a function to convert object of users to array of users and sorting the users based on their score, is there problem in the algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

I created a linear sorting algorithm to sort users based on their scores, when I change user A score and it becomes more than user B, the algorithm output the correct sorted array but it duplicates user B, for example if the array is ['Khaled', 'Ahmed', 'Saad'] when Saad's score becomes more than Ahmad's score, the function output ['Khaled', 'Saad', 'Saad', 'Ahmed']
so is there problem in my algorithm

```
sortedUsers() {


    let {storeState} = this.props

    let users = storeState.users;
    let sortedUsers = [];

    Object.keys(users).map((key) => {

        if(Object.keys(storeState.users).length === sortedUsers.le)
        return

        let user = users[key];
        let userQuestions = user.questions;
        let userAnswersLength = Object.keys(user.answers).length;
        let score1 = userAnswersLength + userQuestions.length;

        if (sortedUsers.length === 0) {
            sortedUsers = [user];
            return;
        }

        sortedUsers.map((user2, index) => {

            let lastIndex = sortedUsers.length - 1;

            let userQuestions = user2.questions;
            let userAnswersLength = Object.keys(user2.answers).length;
            let score2 = userAnswersLength + userQuestions.length;

            if (score1 > score2) {

                sortedUsers.splice(index, 0, user);

            } else if (index === lastIndex) {

                sortedUsers[lastIndex+1] = user;

            }

            console.log(sortedUsers)

        })

    })

    return sortedUsers;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code. It will not work as designed. When you do the second map, you always insert the user object into the `sortedUsers` array next to the `user2` element and you do this for every element in the sorted list. If there are 3 elements in the current `sortedUsers` and you are checking a new user object (from the outer map), you will insert the new object 3 times - before or after every element in the `sortedUsers` list. This is what's causing the duplicates in your result.

For the insert to work correctly, you need to scan the entire `sortedUsers` list to find the correct position of the new user object.